# Insert HTML element based on length of other element in for Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So I want to insert a span element x times based on the length of another html element as with a for loop. I am getting the correct amount returned but I get `undefined` in the html. I know I am doing something wrong in the loop, but can't see where? I have looped over arrays and returned the value before via a for loop, but inserting an element based on the count loop I have not. So I should be inserting the `<span class="pagination-bullet"></span>` say 4 times based on `count`. In html i get **<<s<sp<spa** So definitely something is not right.

```
    var counterElem = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-carousel-slide');
    var count = counterElem.length;
    var paginationCount = count;
    var parentElem = document.querySelector('#main-carousel-pagination');
    var paginationElement = document.createElement('SPAN');
    paginationElement.innerHTML = '<span class="pagination-bullet"></span>';
    var insert = '';
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {      
      insert += `<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet">`[i];
      parentElem.append(insert);
    }
```

So what I would expect is if count = 4, then the html would be:

```
<span class="pagination-bullet"></span>
<span class="pagination-bullet"></span>
<span class="pagination-bullet"></span>
<span class="pagination-bullet"></span>
```

Comment: `t">\`[i];` <-- what is that [i] ??? doing there? Where is the closing `</span>` ?

Comment: obviously wrong approach

Comment: What is the `[i]` supposed to be doing in your eyes?

Comment: [i] = index for the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing `xxxxx`[0] you are saying give me the first index of the string. Hence why you are seeing that weird output.

Assuming you want the number, you would use ${} in your string template literal.

```
insert += `<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet">${i}</span>`;
```

without the number

```
insert += `<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span>`;
```

Can also build the string without the loop.

```
var insert = Array(count).fill('<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet"></span>').join();
parentElem.innerHTML = insert;
```

Comment: Thanks please see updated with HTML to give better understanding.

Comment: Thanks, So why didn't I need the [i] anywhere in the html, is that only for looping over arrays to get the index?

Comment: `[i]` is how you reference an index, you are not trying to reference an array/character so it is not needed.

Comment: I havn't looked into Array(count) yet.. still studying.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
var counterElem = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-carousel-slide');
var count = counterElem.length;
var paginationCount = count;
var parentElem = document.querySelector('#main-carousel-pagination');
var paginationElement = document.createElement('SPAN');
paginationElement.innerHTML = '<span class="pagination-bullet"></span>';
var insert = "";
for (i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {      
          insert += "<span class=\"swiper-pagination-bullet\">" + [i] + "</span>";
}
parentElem.append(insert);
```

Comment: Thanks please see updated with HTML to give better understanding.